# Why rest end-points are not found?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, websphere

I have spring-boot application with spring-boot-starter-web and jpa.
Localy it works ok.

Then, I build war file and try to deploy it on websphere.

My project has next structure:

[image]

And when, after deploy on websphere my application, I load root like ip:port/test - start page from index.html is shown.

But, when try to open some rest of my application - there is 404 error shows.
For send request from client, I try to use postman.

SpringBoot class is:

```
@ComponentScan({"data"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"data.model"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"data.persistence"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

    }
}
```

Without onstartup method,  war failes on server when try to launch.

Comment: I would expect to have the package names to be fully qualified  like `com.mycompany.data`. Or you can just move your Application class into the `com.mycompany` package and get rid of the ComponentScan, EntityScan annotations altogether. Does that work for you?

Comment: If you read the javadoc of [`SpringBootApplication`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/SpringBootApplication.html): *"This is a convenience annotation that is equivalent to declaring `@Configuration`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and `@ComponentScan`"*. So, remove `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and `@ComponentScan`, then specify the package name on `@SpringBootApplication` like this: `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"data"})`

Comment: If you have trouble with `404` errors, perhaps showing us the `@Controller` class you're intending to invoke might allow us to help you.

Comment: Can you move Application class in root package and what spring boot version you are using ?

Comment: Follow the advice from the Spring Boot team and place your `Application` class in a toplevel package. instead of what you have now, then remove all your annotations but `@SpringBootApplication` and restart your app. Because you aren't following the best practice you loose a lot of the auto-config and detection from Spring Boot.

Comment: @kj007 top level is under java or data package do you mean?

Comment: @VladislavOsipenkov under data

Answer (score 1):

This simple example works ok on Liberty, if you want to package your app as an war file, so verify if you have correct setup by trying to run this, then extend with functions that you need.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class SpringBootLibertyApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    //@Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(SpringBootLibertyApplication.class);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello from Spring Boot running on Liberty!";
    }

}
```

UPDATE

Below is `pom.xml` that I used. It is not the most simple one, as in addition, you have Liberty plugin configured, which creates a server based on your server.xml file and also packages final server as jar file. I did that for my own testing so you may comment it out in the pom. I dont have any `web.xml`.

As others already commented, the primary issue in your setup is that your `Application` class is not at the root of the package, and thats confuses all the spring auto configuration features.
So move your `springboot.config.Application` to `data.Application`.

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>gas.tests</groupId>
<artifactId>liberty.springboot</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<!-- contains default pluginManagement configuration for liberty-maven-plugin -->
<parent>
    <groupId>net.wasdev.wlp.maven.parent</groupId>
    <artifactId>liberty-maven-app-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>

    <app.name>LibertySpringBoot</app.name>
    <testServerHttpPort>9080</testServerHttpPort>
    <testServerHttpsPort>9443</testServerHttpsPort>
    <warContext>${app.name}</warContext>
    <package.file>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.zip</package.file>
    <packaging.type>usr</packaging.type>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.wasdev.maven.tools.targets</groupId>
        <artifactId>liberty-target</artifactId>
        <version>18.0.0.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <packagingExcludes>pom.xml</packagingExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Plugin to run unit tests -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <id>default-test</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/it/**</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                        <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/test-reports/unit</reportsDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Enable liberty-maven plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.wasdev.wlp.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>liberty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <assemblyArtifact>
                    <groupId>com.ibm.websphere.appserver.runtime</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wlp-webProfile7</artifactId>
                    <version>18.0.0.2</version>
                    <type>zip</type>
                </assemblyArtifact>
                <configFile>${basedir}/src/main/liberty/config/server.xml</configFile>
                <serverEnv>${basedir}/src/main/liberty/config/server.env</serverEnv>
                <jvmOptionsFile>${basedir}/src/main/liberty/config/jvm.options</jvmOptionsFile>
                <packageFile>${package.file}</packageFile>
                <include>${packaging.type}</include>
                <bootstrapProperties>
                    <app.location>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.war</app.location>
                    <default.http.port>${testServerHttpPort}</default.http.port>
                    <default.https.port>${testServerHttpsPort}</default.https.port>
                </bootstrapProperties>
                <features>
                    <acceptLicense>true</acceptLicense>
                </features>
                <looseApplication>false</looseApplication>
                <serverName>${app.name}Server</serverName>
            </configuration>
            <!-- gas -->
            <executions>
             <execution>
                <id>package-server</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>package-server</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <packageFile>${project.build.directory}/${app.name}-wlp.jar</packageFile>
                    <include>runnable</include>
                </configuration>
             </execution>
            </executions>

        </plugin>
        <!-- Plugin to run functional tests -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>integration-test</phase>
                    <id>integration-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/it/**</include>
                        </includes>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                            <liberty.test.port>${testServerHttpPort}</liberty.test.port>
                            <war.context>${warContext}</war.context>
                        </systemPropertyVariables>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>verify-results</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <summaryFile>${project.build.directory}/test-reports/it/failsafe-summary.xml</summaryFile>
                  <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/test-reports/it</reportsDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>runnable</id>
        <properties>
              <package.file>${project.build.directory}/${app.name}.jar</package.file>
            <packaging.type>runnable</packaging.type>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: Can you share other configs if you have?  I mean pom.xml or web.xml?

Comment: Both options, moving to data package and make test spring-boot Main class are fails. Application not started. It starts only when override onStartup method.